# Bewildering trackpad issue

Tags: trackpad, bug, macos

Macbook (v2018)'s Trackpad was working perfectly fine when it suddenly starts behaving oddly without warning.

Summary :

1. scrolling (2-finger drag) works fine
2. tap doesn't work
3. 2-finger tap (rightclick) doesn't work
4. trying to move the cursor almost never works. doing it with two or three fingers it works sometimes, but it's 'difficult' and chancey.
5. no 'bob' feedback at the lower part of the trackpad (click doesn't register either) (top part of trackpad still works, for presses only, not for taps)

Wiping the trackpad doesn't help. Restarting doesn't help either. I recalled couple months back it had the exact same issue but it somehow managed to recover by itself automagically and I didn't bothered with it after.

What could be the issue? Is it likely to be a hardware issue or software issue or both?

Comment: You might review this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373893/macbook-pro-2018-trackpad-issue-because-of-swollen-battery-or-faulty-trackpad?rq=1 for some troubleshooting tips.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica, in case it it due to a swollen battery, could it have worked, then stop working again?

Comment: I was just looking up the answer I wrote on a swollen battery being a possibility of your track pad failing - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/275291/119271. Either way, it causes physical damage so there’s a good possibility that you’ll still have to change the trackpad even if you solve the battery issue.